# MVVM Button Visibility

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a button that is set to Hidden in my ViewModel constructor.  When the user clicks on an item the button should become visible.  My break points and messagebox show that the value of the Visibility is being change to "Visible" So I'm not sure what  I am missing in my binding.

XAML:

```
    <Button  
        Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.Row="2"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Margin="105,22,0,21" 
        Style="{StaticResource MetroButton}" 
        Width="90" 
        Height="57" 
        Click="btn_Update_Click" 
        RenderTransformOrigin="0.49,0.287"
        Visibility="{Binding Btn_Update_Visibility, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <TextBlock Text="Update Request" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    </Button>
```

ViewModel:

Items User can select:

```
private DataRowView select_request;
public DataRowView Select_Request
{
    get { return select_request; }
    set
    {
        select_request = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Select_Request");

        //Get the Check Request ID
        OnSelect_RequestChange();

        //Make Update Button Visible
        OnSelect_Row();
    }
}
```

Value to Bind Visibility To in XAML

```
private string btn_update_visiblity;
public string Btn_Update_Visibility
{
    get { return btn_update_visiblity; }
    set
    {
        btn_update_visiblity = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Btn_Update_Visibility");
    }
}
```

Method that is called when user selects row

```
public void OnSelect_Row()
{
    btn_update_visiblity = "Visible";
    MessageBox.Show("Update Button is " + Btn_Update_Visibility.ToString());
}
```

Edit: Adding Constructor
My Constructor:

```
    public LandingPageMVVM()
    {
        Search_User = MyCommonValues.UserName;

        btn_update_visiblity = "Hidden";
        //Check if Manager
        #region Manager Check

        bool? manager_check = MyCommonValues.manager_check;
        if (manager_check == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Welcome Manager");
            btn_review_visibility = "Visible";
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Welcome User");
            btn_review_visibility = "Hidden";
        }
     }
```

Comment: One thing I still do not understand is why does my MessageBox.Show(Btn_Update_Visibility) shows a change in value, even though I am changing the btn_update_visibility variable.  Wouldn't this trigger the OnPropertyChange() method?

Comment: Side note, grab a copy of the framework design guidelines. Or, alternatively, if you don't see a style in the .net framework, don't use it. Hungarian notation and_underscores_in_names aren't used (except in autogenerated event handler names which is so embarrassing), and if other people see you using it they'll think you aren't as skilled in the language. It can hurt you in job interviews and in code reviews.

Comment: Essentially when in doubt use camel case?

Comment: When in doubt, "how does Microsoft format this?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are setting the value of `btn_update_visibility` field directly instead of via the `Btn_Update_Visibility` property. This means the `OnPropertyChanged("Btn_Update_Visibility")` method never gets called to indicate the view needs to change.

Instead your code should be:

```
public void OnSelect_Row()
{
    Btn_Update_Visibility = "Visible";
    MessageBox.Show("Update Button is " + Btn_Update_Visibility.ToString());
}
```

Partially related though is your naming of variables and methods. Common C# convention, which would clarify your code somewhat would have it a little more like this (with some other styling improvements too):

```
private string _buttonUpdateVisibility;

public string ButtonUpdateVisibility
{
    get => _buttonUpdateVisibility;
    set
    {
        _buttonUpdateVisibility= value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ButtonUpdateVisibility));
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay thank you, I am still a little confused on how INotifyPropertyChange() works.

Comment: In my constructor I check if the user is an Admin, if so more controls ar made "Visible".  I do this by setting the private strings = "Visible" without any issues.  Does this work because it is in the contructor and therefore never has to watch for OnPropertyChange()? Thanks still learning the ins and outs of MVVM.  (I added my constructor to my question)